# Angular template and passed in object variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="entity in myItems">
     <div data-entity-vignette="true">
     </div>
  </div>
```

Entity Vignette is defined as an attribute directive here:

```
.directive('entityVignette', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '../Assets/Scripts/entityVignette.html'
    }
});
```

and entityVignette.html contains

```
<div>{{ entity.DisplayName }}</div>
```

My question, is how can code my template so that `entityVignette.html` does not depend on the variable name `entity`

That is, to work with my variable of entity, I must use `data-ng-repeat="entity in myItems"`, how could I make it work so that enitityVignette.html doesn't care if it's named **entity** or for instance **item**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to isolate the scope of your directive. For example, declare you directive like this:

```
.directive('entityVignette', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {nameToDisplay:'='},
        templateUrl: '../Assets/Scripts/entityVignette.html'
    }
});
```

Use it like this:

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="entity in myItems">
     <div data-entity-vignette="true" data-name-to-display="entity.DisplayName">
     </div>
  </div>
```

And in your template just do this:

```
<div>{{ nameToDisplay }}</div>
```